# Evaluation puzzle

Tags: core-language

I am puzzled by a couple evaluation outcomes, labelled with question marks (*Mathematica* 11.0).  If these are as they should be, please help me understand why.

```
ClearAll[x, f1, f2]
(* puzzle 1: *)
x = 2;
ReplaceAll[x, x -> 25]  (* 25 ?? *)
ReplaceAll[3 x, x -> 25]  (* 6 *)
(* puzzle 2: *)
f1[x_] := 1 x /. {x -> 25}
f1[2] (* 25 ?? *)
f2[x_] := 1.0 x /. {x -> 25}
f2[2](* 2. *)
```

Comment: Quality material. I had to think twice about it. Thank you :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ReplaceAll[x, x -> 25]` evaluates as:

```
ReplaceAll[2, 2 -> 25]
25
```

`ReplaceAll[3 x, x -> 25]`  evaluates as:

```
ReplaceAll[3*2, 2 -> 25] 
ReplaceAll[6, 2 -> 25]
6
```

If you're confused, [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) it.

```
ReplaceAll[x, x -> 25]  // TracePrint

 x/. x->25

  ReplaceAll

  x

  2

  x->25

   Rule

   x

   2

   25

  2->25

  2->25

   Rule

   2

   25

 2/. 2->25

 25
```

If you find the `Trace` output confusing, try `On[]` and `Off[]` in a terminal.  Don't try this in a notebook, as there is so much behind the scenes evaluation in recent versions that it will clog up your notebook and maybe even freeze the front end.

```
In[4]:= On[]; ReplaceAll[x, x -> 25]; Off[]                                     

On::trace: On[] --> Null.

x::trace: x --> 2.

x::trace: x --> 2.

Rule::trace: x -> 25 --> 2 -> 25.

Rule::trace: 2 -> 25 --> 2 -> 25.

ReplaceAll::trace: x /. x -> 25 --> 2 /. 2 -> 25.

ReplaceAll::trace: 2 /. 2 -> 25 --> 25.
```